# Smallest value for P(A)=P(B)=P(C) s.t. P(A and B and C) always exceeds 0.95

Tags: probability

**What is the smallest value for P(A)=P(B)=P(C) s.t. P(A and B and C) always exceeds 0.95?**

I have made some attempts:

P(A and B and C)=P(A)P(B|A)P(C|A and B)>0.95. But how should the conditinal probabilities be handled?

or

P(A and B and C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A and B)-P(A and C)-P(B and C)+P(A or B or C)>0.95. It is unknown whether the events are independent or not e.g. P(A and C) is not necassary zero, so how to proceed in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Considering the complements, clearly 0.983333....

Comment: Are there some other constraints? If you let $A=B=C$, then choosing $pA = 0.95$ yields the minimum.

Comment: No other constraints. P(A) >= 0.98333 is the right answer. I'm not sure how to consider the complements in this case but thank you for your answer, now I got a clue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider minimizing $P(A\cap B \cap C) $ subject to $P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = p$.
In the following Venn diagram,

[image]

$$\eqalign{P(A \cap B \cap C) &= p_3\cr
         P(A) = p &= p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4\cr
         P(B) = p &= p_2 + p_3 + p_5 + p_6\cr 
         P(C) = p &= p_3 + p_4 + p_6 + p_7\cr
         &p_1 + \ldots + p_8 = 1\cr}$$

Given $p$, minimizing $p_3$ with these constraints and all variables nonnegative is a linear programming problem.  When $p$ is near $1$, the 
optimal solution will have $p_1 = p_5 = p_7 = p_8 = 0$, $p_2 = p_4 = p_6 = 1-p$ and $p_3 = 3 p - 2$.  Thus to have $p_3 = .95$ you need $p = 2.95/3 = .98333\ldots$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this fine solution!

Answer (score 0):

$\min P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - 1$ if not negative or $0$ otherwise

Similarly $\min P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - 2$ for same condition as above.

Here let $P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = x$, and minimum intersection is given: 0.95

So, solving equation $( 0.95 = 3x - 2 )$ gives $x = 0.983$

Comment: You can edit and see the Latex code.